# Give custom page template a custom post ID

Tags: plugins, customization, pages, page-template, id

I created several custom pages in WordPress.  One displays real estate listings.  When you click on the listing it opens into another custom page I created.

The problem is no matter which listing I click on the custom page always has the same post id.  This is preventing me from being able to allow users to save their favorite listings as most favorite plugins use the post id to identify a page.

Is there a way to give custom pages their own post id?

Comment: It depends on how the custom pages were implemented. This behaviour is highly unusual. Are these pages in the WordPress database or are you displaying custom content based on a query argument or custom rewrite rule?

Comment: Hey, I'm using a json url to display the real estate listings.  They listings appear on one page in a grid.  When you click on a property it opens to a new page that displays the property's specific details.  These details are also coming from the json data.  [link] (http://geekoutaustin.com/theme1/mls/)

Comment: The only way to give the property an ID would be to import it into the WordPress database as a post. The only other option is to implement your own bookmarking functionality based on the `?id=` parameter. I would not expect any existing favouriting plugins to have bothered to account for your highly unusual and specific circumstances. Whether any given favouriting plugin has a workaround that you could use would depend entirely on how that plugin was implemented, and you'd need to ask its author.